# How to have grayscale and rainbow color plots in subplots?

Tags: matlab, subplot

I have a MATLAB code snippet that uses `subplot` to generate some plots in the same figure. However, I want to make `surf` plots in  `subplot(3,3,2)`, `subplot(3,3,5)`, `subplot(3,3,8)` colorful instead of grayscale and keep `subplot(1,3,1)`, `subplot(3,3,3)`, `subplot(3,3,6)`, `subplot(3,3,9)` grayscale. How can I achieve that?

```
img = imread('moon.tif');

subplot(1,3,1);
imagesc(img);
colormap(gray);
title('moon.tif');
axis tight; axis equal;

subplot(3,3,2);
sigma = 3;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma); % typically we would choose to filter width to be six times sigma
surf(gaussianfilter);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

subplot(3,3,3);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
imagesc(img_filtered);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;

subplot(3,3,5);
sigma = 9;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma);
surf(gaussianfilter);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

subplot(3,3,6);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
imagesc(img_filtered);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;

subplot(3,3,8);
sigma = 15;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma);
surf(gaussianfilter);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

subplot(3,3,9);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
image(img_filtered);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the desired axes to the `colormap` function, and specify the color scheme (e.g., jet, gray, etc.) you want to display. The axes can be obtained from the `subplot` function.

Try this code:

```
img = imread('moon.tif');

ax1 = subplot(1,3,1);
imagesc(img);
colormap(ax1, gray);
title('moon.tif');
axis tight; axis equal;

ax2 = subplot(3,3,2);
sigma = 3;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma); % typically we would choose to filter width to be six times sigma
surf(gaussianfilter);
colormap(ax2, jet);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

ax3 = subplot(3,3,3);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
imagesc(img_filtered);
colormap(ax3, gray);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;

ax5 = subplot(3,3,5);
sigma = 9;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma);
surf(gaussianfilter);
colormap(ax5, jet);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

ax6 = subplot(3,3,6);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
imagesc(img_filtered);
colormap(ax6, gray);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;

ax8 = subplot(3,3,8);
sigma = 15;
gaussianfilter = fspecial('gaussian', [90,90], sigma);
surf(gaussianfilter);
colormap(ax8, jet);
title(['Gaussian filter \sigma = ', num2str(sigma)]);

ax9 = subplot(3,3,9);
img_filtered = conv2(img, gaussianfilter, 'same');
image(img_filtered);
colormap(ax9, gray);
title('Filtered image');
axis tight; axis equal;
```